# Combine rows together that are duplicates

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 4 columns and several thousands rows.  The first two columns are geographical identifiers, the third one is a date, and the last one is the number of shipments in that date.

For example:

```
London UK 4/4/2018 1
London UK 4/4/2018 1
London UK 4/5/2018 3
London UK 4/5/2018 2
```

I would like to combine the rows so as to have only one row per city, country, and date.

For example, the above data would become:

```
London UK 4/4/2018 2
London UK 4/5/2018 5
```

Thank you for all help in advance.

Comment: you can use dplyr's group_by to group by the first three columns and use summarise to sum the shipments

Comment: What have you tired till now?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:

```
# 1. Data set
df <- data.frame(
  country = c("UK", "UK", "UK", "UK"),
  city = c("London", "London", "London", "London"),
  date = c("4/4/2018", "4/4/2018", "4/5/2018", "4/5/2018"),
  shipment = c(1, 1, 3, 2))

# 2. Group by 'country', 'city', and 'date' features
df %>% 
  group_by(country, city, date) %>% 
  summarise(shipment = sum(shipment))
```